# Finding the SVD of particular rank $1$, $4 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, svd

I am preparing for a Numerical Analysis exam, and one of the practice questions is the following:

> Find both a reduced and full SVD of
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 4\\
> 1 & 0 & 4\\
> 1 & 0 & 4\\
> 1 & 0 & 4\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

I would only have about 10-15 minutes to work on this problem. I have a partial solution below, but I am wondering if there is any faster way to do it, since my method seems long and unreliable (after finding a reduced SVD, I found the full SVD by trial and error).

**My Solution:** $A$ has rank $1$, so a reduced SVD is of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4\\
1 & 0 & 4\\
1 & 0 & 4\\
1 & 0 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}u_1 \\u_2\\u_3\\u_4 \end{bmatrix} [\sigma] \begin{bmatrix}\overline{v_1} & \overline{v_2} & \overline{v_3}  \end{bmatrix} = u \sigma v^*.$$
We know that $\{ u \}$ is a basis for $Col(A) = \langle \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T\rangle$, so $u$ is of the form $u = \begin{bmatrix}x & x & x & x \end{bmatrix}^T$. Since $||u||_2 = 1$, we must have $u = \pm \begin{bmatrix}\frac 12 & \frac 12 & \frac 12 & \frac 12 \end{bmatrix}^T$. We will chose the positive sign.

Similarly, $\{v \}$ is a basis for $Col(A^*) = \langle \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}^T \rangle$ , and using $||v||_2 = 1$, we must have $v = \pm \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}} & 0 & \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}} \end{bmatrix}^T$. We will chose the positive sign. Finally, to find $\sigma$, look at the big SVD factorization of $A$ above. Equating entries $(1, 1)$ on both sides gives $ \frac 12 \sigma \frac {1}{\sqrt{17}}= 1$, which gives $\sigma = \frac {2}{\sqrt{17}}.$ Therefore a reduced SVD of $A$ is
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}  1/2 \\ 1/2\\\ 1/2\\ 1/2 \end{bmatrix} [2\sqrt{17}] \begin{bmatrix}\frac {1}{\sqrt{17}} & 0 & \frac {4}{\sqrt{17}} \end{bmatrix} $$

To find a full SVD, we just have to extend $u$ and $v$ to orthonormal matrices. I did this by basically guessing. An orthonormal extension of $u$ is

$$\frac 12 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and an orthonormal extension of $v$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1/\sqrt{17} & 0 & 5/\sqrt{17}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
5/\sqrt{17} & 0 & -1/\sqrt{17}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, a full SVD of $A$ is
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
\frac 12 & -\frac 12  & \frac 12  & -\frac 12 \\
\frac 12  & \frac 12  & -\frac 12  & -\frac 12 \\
\frac 12  & \frac 12  & \frac 12  & \frac 12 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2 \sqrt {17} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/\sqrt{17} & 0 & 5/\sqrt{17}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
5/\sqrt{17} & 0 & -1/\sqrt{17}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This seems to be a very quick method, and it’s definitely what I would do. Is there a specific part that your trying to optimize?

Comment: @paulinho Thank you. I don't have a specific part I'm trying to optimize, I am just wondering if there is a better way. The matrix is not only rank 1, but also it has a very special form (in every column, the elements are equal). My method works for any rank 1 matrices, with the exception that it may be harder to guess a full SVD after finding the reduced one. So I am worried that perhaps I am not taking full advantage of the structure of the matrix.

Comment: Also I haven't timed myself while writing the solution at full speed, but I'm afraid it may take me more than 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems fairly quick. The only thing that I would consider optimizing is the extension to an orthonormal basis.

First of all, an approach to be considered is writing something like

> To find the full SVD, it suffices to extend $u$ and $v$ to orthonormal bases $(u,u_2,u_3,u_4)$ and $(v,v_2,v_3)$. With that, we can see that $A$ has full SVD $A = U \Sigma V^T$, with
> $$
> U = \pmatrix{u & u_2 & u_3 & u_4}, \quad \Sigma = \pmatrix{2\sqrt{17}&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0 &0\\ 0&0&0}, \quad V = \pmatrix{v_1&v_2&v_3}
> $$

and simply giving this as the "full answer". I would suspect that this would get you most of the partial credit.

That said, if you **must** compute an orthonormal basis, then the standard approach is the [Gram Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). For instance, we can get the extension to $U$ by applying the procedure to the list $(u,e_1,e_2,e_3)$, where $e_1,\dots,e_4$ denote the standard basis vectors, i.e. the columns of the size-$4$ identity matrix.

However, we can indeed take advantage of the fact that $u$ is the vector of equal elements. In particular, we can always extend such a matrix into an orthonormal basis by using the columns of the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix). Alternatively, since the dimension of the space is a power of $2$, we could do the same by considering the columns of a scaled [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix).

In general, we can also extend $v$ to such a basis in a nice fashion using the fact that $u \in \Bbb R^3$. In particular, for $v_2$ we can select any vector orthogonal to $v$, then take the cross-product $v \times v_2$ as a third vector. However, I prefer your method which simply takes advantage of the zero-entry in $v$.